# Getting custom XMP metadata using metadata-extractor in c#

Tags: c#, photoshop-script, xmp, metadata-extractor

I am writing some XMP metadata using a photoshop .jsx script using :

`var xmp = new XMPMeta( activeDocument.xmpMetadata.rawData);
 XMPMeta.registerNamespace(nameSpace, nsPrefix);`

and then adding some data to this new namespace. I am able to view it in Photoshop by checking under `File -> FileInfo`. My question is how can I access this data using the metadata extractor library in my c# project ? When I use the following code I do not see the new metadata I added inside any of the directories:

`FileStream OriginalFile = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\av\\Desktop\\test.tif",  FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
 IEnumerable<MetadataExtractor.Directory> directories = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(OriginalFile);`

**Edit:**
I am able to loop through all the properties but when I try to do

`var xmpDirectory = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata("path/test.tif").OfType<XmpDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();
xmpDirectory.XmpMeta.GetProperty("http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/xmpMM:DerivedForm/", "stRef:documentID")`

I get an exception. The property is present when I look at it through Photoshop.

[xmp data in photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dgTH.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMP data is stored in the `XmpDirectory`. Access it via:

```
var xmpDirectory = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata("path\test.tif")
    .OfType<XmpDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Note however that XMP data in metadata-extractor does not follow the standard tag/value format of other directories. Instead, you should access the `XmpMeta` property of the directory in order to inspect that data.

You can then write code resembling:

```
foreach (var property in xmpDirectory.XmpMeta.Properties)
    Console.WriteLine($"Path={property.Path} Namespace={property.Namespace} " +
                       "Value={property.Value}");
```

Some more discussion [here](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/wiki/XMP) and more information about the XMP library [here](https://github.com/drewnoakes/xmp-core-dotnet).

Comment: where is XmpDirectory ? It does not seem to be a part of XmpCore or MetadataExtractor.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I found it.

Comment: @DrewNoakes: Can't find those data: `FirstOrDefault` returns null on all my images (Canon CR2 from various cameras). Still data exists, I see them in Photoshop. Any clue?

Comment: @PPC the data is probably not stored as XMP. If you're sure it is, please open an issue and attach a sample image.